# sap hana calculated column check for multiple IDs

Tags: if-statement, expression, calculated-columns, hana

i want to create a calculated column, which will show two values: Y or N

2 columns are here important, "VAT-ID" and "CUSTOMER-ID". the calculated column will check if a customer-ID has multiple VAT-IDs. If yes the value "Y" should be displayed, else "N".

for example, the first 5 rows of the customer-id column are: 
123456

654321

666666

123456

654321

the first 5 rows of the VAT-id column are:
EE999999999

AA999999999

GG999999999

KK999999999

AA999999999

the first 5 rows of the calculated column should be then:
Y

N

N

Y

N

any Help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculated columns don’t allow for aggregations across groups or other than the current row.

What you can do to achieve your goal is to create a separate aggregation node and count distinct `VAT-IDs` grouped by `CUSTOMER-ID`.

With this, you can now have a calculated column that checks for `VAT-ID-COUNT > 1` and map it to your `Y`/`N` values.

Answer (score 0):

As Lars mentioned it is not possible to use a window function within a [calculated field on HANA table](http://www.kodyaz.com/sap-abap/create-calculated-column-in-sap-hana-database-table.aspx)

But you can use following query to check if VAT number is multiple for a customer or not

```
select
CustomerId, VATID,
case 
    when (count(*) over (partition by CustomerId, VATID)) > 1 
    then 'Y' 
    else 'N' 
end
from CustomerVAT;
```